# Change UIbutton Image on click

Tags: objective-c

I have stored 5 images in an mutable array and displayed them randomly on iPhone view by appending them in UIButton . now I want to change the image on a button on which I will click. but in my code only the last image changes not the image on which I called the action.

Comment: I've trimmed a number of requests for urgency from your questions. In general it is not a good idea to add this to questions, since readers here are overwhelmingly volunteers, and they do not take well to being hurried. Please refrain from adding this in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code for 3 buttons which highlights the clicked button

```
-(void) changeButtonImage:(id) sender{
    [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button1Image_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button2Image_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button3Image_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIButton *button = sender;

    if (button.tag == 0) {
        [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button1Image_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if (button.tag == 1) {
        [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button2Image_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if (button.tag == 2) {
        [button3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button3Image_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

hope this helps...

hAPPY cODING...

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for how to change the image on a button just do:

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can have it loop through your array but creating a variable to store what image index you are on. Then just go to the next one using the statement above to assign the image.

Comment: I have 5 images and I am calling them randomly to generate grid of 5*5. In this grid, images are displayed randomly. Now what I want is when I click or tab any image within this grid then the image  should get change. but when I click any image within the grid only the last image gets change i,e., image at (5,5) position. hre I have taken buttons and set images over it. That mean I have a 5*5 grid of image-buttons. Now please help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an Outlet (IBOutlet) for each of the buttons.  You should list each one as an outlet, and just use Interface Builder to connect each button to those variables.  Then create a function for the touchUpInside event of each button.  Make this buttonPressed.  make this function something like:

```
-(void) buttonPressed:(id) sender
{
     ((UIButton *)sender).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
}
```

You will want to set a variable like currentImage to track what image is set.  Each time you click increase that variable (currentImage++).  If it gets > some final amount set it back to 0.  Then you can just do

```
if (currentImage == 0) { set first image; } else if (currentImage == 1) { set second image.. }
```

etc...

Does this help?